# How can I compare the numerical value of generator object to the numerical value of a float efficiently without error?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error, generator, typeerror

I am trying to do a comparison of values, where `y` is a list of values.

```
if max(y) > 1 or max(y) == 1:
    ydel = 0.5
elif max(y) < 1:
    ydel = 0.005
```

When run, the first line of the code above yields an error.

```
>> TypeError: unorderable types: generator() > int()
```

Since max() is apparently a built-in generator that generates objects on the fly, I thought I should maybe store the value in a variable, aptly named `peak`.

```
peak = max(y)
if peak > 1:
    ydel = 0.5
else:
    ydel = 0.005
```

Running this yields the same error as before. So, I tried

```
peak = float(max(y))
if peak > 1:
    ydel = 0.5
else:
    ydel = 0.005
```

but `float` is a generator object as well (as is `int`); this yields the error

```
>> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'
```

I thought about defining a function that returns a variable containing the generator object, but I don't think it will work since storing the generator object in variable `peak` did not work. I also thought about trying to find the maximum value iteratively but this is costly in my case as I'm considering multiple distributions, each of which consists of several thousand data points and each if which is in need of optimizing.

Is there a way to do this non-iteratively without generators that is still efficient? Or perhaps a better way of assigning the generator value to a variable to maximize efficiency?

Comment: The builtin `max()` is not a generator function; you must have shadowed it by previously defining or importing another function with that name.

Comment: Are you sure `y` is a list? It seems like `y` is a list holding a generator. `print(y)` would be very instructive.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus That would explain why it worked earlier. I tried searching for all uses of `max` in the code (via `ctrl + f`) and it is only used to define other variables. I'm thinking it may have been imported alongside `cosh` from the math module, just waiting on the code to finish running.. It might be another module, will update when found.

Comment: @tdelaney I am sure that `y` is a list. It is not included in the question but the code prints results as it runs, so I can see that `y` is a list. I've even included `y` as a list that is plotted against `x-data`.

Comment: Assuming `max` is still the builtin function, that's really the only way to explain what you see. Posting the print will show us what the data is. The question really should have the data that causes the crash to be complete, and that would do it.

Comment: It would be pretty easy to accidentally do `[some_generator]` instead of `list(some_generator)` and get what you see.

Comment: @tdelaney I hadn't considered the possibility of a single-item list; that is indeed very possible.

Comment: It's a few hundred lines of code so it may take a bit of time to find. Before importing new modules, the code worked decently. I was just trying to make it more user-friendly. But if you'd like to see a print statement and working sample to confirm, here are a [subset of print statements](https://i.imgur.com/pAskl5w.png) (y is a list, y[i] represents exp value of i-th bin) and a [graph](https://i.imgur.com/OzQg8gO.png) that uses y.

Comment: @tdelaney I believe that was it. I copy-pasted the code into a new script with minor edits and it runs fine.

Comment: Yea! Either @ZeroPiraeus or I was going to be right... I couldn't think of any other explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` returns a single object from a sequence. If it returns a generator, then a generator was in that sequence. Python 3 tightened up the rules for comparing dissimilar things. So, if you try to compare an `int` to a `generator` you get an error:

```
>>> mygen > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: generator() > int()
```

Same applies for things that just don't have a natural order

```
>>> mygen > mygen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: generator() > generator()
```

If a sequence is a single generator, you get the generator. If it has a generator and anything else, you get an error.

```
>>> mygen = (i for i in range(3))
>>> max([mygen])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5a79668240>
>>> max([1,mygen])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: generator() > int()
```

In the end there were only two possible explanations for your problem. Either `y` has a generator in it somewhere or `max` is shadowed by a completely different function.